# Roaming Administrator Profile

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a 2012 R2 AD server running 100%. A certain group of users need to be able to run programs that require elevation and install programs as needed. I have tried making the user a member of Administrators but the UAC prompt still pops up for a Administrator authentication and when the user enters their username and password . The idea here is to have User A log on to any computer and be able to run programs as administrator without having to make that user a local admin on every machine.

[image: Require Elevation]

Answer (score 1):

The users should be made a local admin in each machine that they need to administer. You should **not** add users to Domain Admins to accomplish this.

If you don't want to set this manually on each PC, you should use Group Policy Preferences or Restricted Groups to manage group membership.